# clr and kivy conflict with factory.py import error

Tags: python, crash, kivy, clr, python.net

When I want to import clr, then My kivy env got crashed.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "demo.py", line 86, in <module>
        demoApp().run()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 801, in run
        self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 598, in load_kv
        root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
        return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 379, in load_string
        widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)()
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 139, in __getattr__
        module = __import__(name=item['module'], fromlist='.')
    TypeError: __import__() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: is this using pythonnet?

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/547